# How can i use chef attribute value in my jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra

I have a requirement for which I will have to execute command **knife node run_list set hostname role[abc]**  from Jenkins job where the **hostname** should be picked up from the chef role file attribute value.

Comment: Maybe explain why this is the requirement.  I can't think of any reason you'd be pulling a hostname from a role attribute.

Comment: In my case I am not sure as to which hostname will my user apply a specific chef role. I will have to take the hostname as part of my role attribute and then execute knife command to apply the role to that specific host

Comment: so, how will the node be added to the role attribute file?

Comment: So I was thinking if I could add an attribute to one of my cookbook recipie e.g. node.default[opt-wrap-apache][nodename]=<hostname> and then reference this attribute in my role json file. But my issue is ... I cannot figure out how to get this hostname inside my Jenkins job.

Comment: I think you are doing this inside out.  Rather than setting node.default[opt-wrap-apache][nodename] = <hostname>, you should be adding the role to the node's runlist directly.  If you're actually adding a node to this attribute INSIDE a recipe, then please expand the question to show some sample code and explain why you are taking that approach.